# how to use conditional operator in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO `employee_master` ( em_first_name, em_middle_name, em_last_name, em_gender, em_DOB, em_DOJ, em_mobile_no, em_alternate_mobile_no, em_landline_no, em_permanent_address, em_corresponding_address, em_email_id ) VALUES(

        '" . $params["txtFirstName"] . "',
        '" . $params["txtMiddleName"] . "', 
        '" . $params["txtLastName"] . "',

        '" . $params["selGender"] . "',
        '" . $params["txtDOB"] . "',
        '" . $params["txtDOJ"] . "',
        '" . $params["txtMobileNo"] . "',
        '" . $params["txtAlternateMobileNo"] . "',
        '" . $params["txtLandlineNo"] . "',
        '" . $params["txtPermanentAddressTextarea"] . "',
        '" . $params["txtCorrespondingAddressTextarea"] . "',
        '" . $params["txtEmailID"] . "');  ";
    //echo $sql;
    echo $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql) or die("Error to insert User.");

}
```

($('#selReligion').val() == -1 ) ? " " : $('#selReligion').val(),

Here I want to use Conditional operator. 
Right Now..if selGender is null that It inserts -1 
but i want to insert 0 or null

Comment: You code is at risk of [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection). You should use prepared statements with parameters.

Comment: You're already using an API that supports **prepared statements** with bounded variable input, you should utilize parameterized queries with placeholders (prepared statements) to protect your database against [SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)!
 Get started with [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) and [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param()`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param).

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking. Do you want to insert `-1`, `0` or `null`?

Comment: And what have you tried?  Have you looked up what the conditional operator is?  When you actually use it, what doesn't work?

Comment: <div class="form-group">

                <label for="name" class="control-label">Gender:*</label>
                  <select  class="form-control" id="selGender" name="selGender">
                        <option value="-1">Select Gender</option>
                        <option value="Male">Male</option>
                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                  
                  </select>
                  </div>

Comment: The above code is from code that designed like that

Comment: If the option is not selected -1 will be inserted but I don't want to insert -1. I want to insert null

Comment: @Karthik: Then why not just make that value empty in the HTML?

Comment: But I am Validating selGender If it is -1 that should alert.

Comment: `0 IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. Modify your original post to add any new information.

Comment: yes I want to use null

Comment: @Karthik: The conditional operator you've edited into the question is JavaScript, not PHP.  It's not clear at all what the actual problem is here or what specifically you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ternary operator. It will insert the 0 instead of -1, as you require.
if `$params["selGender"]` will not be null then it will insert the value otherwise 0. and you can change the condition in that according to your need.

```
'" . (!empty($params["selGender"])) ? $params["selGender"] : 0 . "',
```

**EDITED:**

Other way to achieve this is:

Take a variable:

```
$selGender = '0';
if(!empty($params["selGender"]))
   $selGender = $params["selGender"];
```

And then use this variable:

```
'" . $selGender . "',
```

Comment: "Try this" does not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: The above code is working. any other thing Code Lover

Comment: @Karthik What other thing do you want to know??

Comment: any other options

Comment: ($('#selReligion').val() == -1 ) ? " " : $('#selReligion').val(),    this is my javascript conditional operator.